# Different spark working directory for spill, sort, shuffle

Tags: apache-spark

Does spark support multiple directories for each of its components that rely on disk?

e.g. spill, external sorting & storing shuffle files?

e.g. we want spill & external sorting to happen on fast SSD's whereas shuffle files can be stored on a EBS attached volume

Currently the only config i see is `spark.local.dirs`

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in the [documentation](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/42bc297d5b9149730f91af26c857897bf4d6aa91/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/util/Utils.scala#L926) of the `getConfiguredLocalDirs` function, there are currently 5 ways of specifying local dirs to spill to (with `java.io.tmpdir` as a fallback):

- If running in YARN mode, this will return a directory chosen by YARN.
- If the `SPARK_EXECUTOR_DIRS` environment variable is set, this will return a directory from it.
- If the `SPARK_LOCAL_DIRS` environment variable is set, this will return a directory from it.
- If running in Mesos mode and `SHUFFLE_SERVICE_ENABLED = false`, this will return a directory chosen by Mesos.
- Otherwise, if the `spark.local.dir` is set, this will return a directory from it.
- Otherwise, this will return java.io.tmpdir.

This `getConfiguredLocalDirs` function is used in the `getLocalDirs` [function](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/42bc297d5b9149730f91af26c857897bf4d6aa91/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/util/Utils.scala#L879), which is finally used to define what the local directories are. So there are different ways of specifying directories to spill to, but no ways to choose which types of spill go to which directories.

Finally, and this is an opinion, I'm not sure this would ever be interesting. Any type of disk spill results from a lack of memory from the same storage pool (the execution memory, see [this page](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/tuning.html#memory-management-overview) for more info), so prioritizing one type of spill w.r.t. the other will only add complexity for no gain.

Hope this helps!